# "JsonParser$Feature is a restricted class." error on Google App Engine while authorizing BigQuery Access

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have a Google App Engine project that I'm trying to implement Google BigQuery for XML caching.I'm using the [CredentialUtils](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization) class from BQ tutorials for offline web server authorization. I have created the client_secrets and all that.

I've been trying my best for solving this, tried newest library releases yet to no avail. What would you suggest?

Here's the error log.

```
Mar 12, 2013 3:58:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:56876/
Mar 12, 2013 3:58:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:56876/_ah/admin
Mar 12, 2013 3:59:04 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /cachetest
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser$Feature is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.<clinit>(JsonFactory.java:65)
at com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:44)
at gigs.db.bigquery.CredentialUtils.<clinit>(CredentialUtils.java:31)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
at gigs.engine.auth.XMLGetter.saveInCache(XMLGetter.java:156)
at gigs.engine.auth.XMLGetter.getEventXML(XMLGetter.java:74)
at gigs.CacheTestServlet.doGet(CacheTestServlet.java:42)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question, but why not use App Engine Service accounts? https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-appengine